# Сделать кнопку не активной

Tags: html, jquery

Как сделать кнопку не активной(сероватой что ли), пока допустим поле в таблице БД не примет значение 1, а если пользователь все же нажмет на неактивную кнопку, то появлялся алерт?

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать и что не получается? Покажите код

Answer (score 1):

Как пример можно сделать так (пример для input, если хотите то в value="значение из БД"):

```
<div>
    <label>Введите значение</label>
    <input type="text" data-val="1">
    <button>Кнопка</button>
</div>
<script>
    //код с подключенной библиотекой jquery

    $('button').click(function(){
        if($(this).prev().val() == $(this).prev().data('val')) {
            location.href = '/done/';
        }
        else {
            //либо редирект на страницу ошибки 
        }
    })

</script>
```

Comment: ставлю в data-val 0, но кнопка все равно активна

Comment: все, разобрался